# Make LaTeX ignore line breaks in the source

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to be able to write a few lines like:

```
a
b
c
```

in my LaTeX source code file, and have it come out as `abc` instead of `a b c`. (This is because in my use case, each line is a long and complicated thing, so concatenating all the lines in the source code ends up being completely unreadable.)

Is there a magic thing I can add at the end of each line to make it ignore the next line break?

Comment: You could add a `%` to make LaTeX ignore the line break/space. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864

Comment: @moewe: exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Want to make your comment an answer so I can mark that question as resolved?

Comment: Would you OK with marking the question as a duplicate of the one I linked to above? That is what we usually do for "unwanted spaces induced by line break" questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)